# How to run filters on dotnet tests

Tags: testing, code-coverage, xunit.net, azure-pipelines-build-task, reportgenerator

I have a build in VSTS, as follows:

[image]

You can see from the screen shot there's a test step to "Test and generate code coverage".  It uses this command:

> /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura
>   /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\Coverage\coverage

Which allows the code coverage report to be generated.  I have added "Categories" to my xUnit tests with my defined Trait (such as integration or unit), to allow me to filter tests during build/release.  Example would be:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Xunit.Abstractions;
    using Xunit.Sdk;

    /// <summary>
    /// Decorates a test as a Unit Test, so that it runs in Continuous Integration builds.
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public sealed class IsUnitAttribute : AICategoryAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="IsUnitAttribute"/>
        /// </summary>
        public IsUnitAttribute() : base("Unit") { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decorates a test as an Integration Test, so that it runs in Continuous Integration builds.
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public sealed class IsIntegrationAttribute : AICategoryAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="IsIntegrationAttribute"/>
        /// </summary>
        public IsIntegrationAttribute() : base("Integration") { }
    }
```

I only know how to apply a filter in VS-Test step, as follows:

But not when I'm testing using dotnet:

[image]

I only know how to build code coverage using dotnet (and not VS-Test)… I want to do both!  How do I:

a) Add the commands to the VS-Test to generate the code coverage, the same as I do for dotnet using the command above.

OR

b) Apply the filter to the dotnet Test step?

Any pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't the `Test Filter criteria` filed for the dotnet test step. However you can try running the dotnet test with the arguments `--filter` in command line.

Please see [Filter option details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21#filter-option-details)

> Filters out tests in the current project using the given expression.
>   For more information, see the Filter option details section. For more
>   information and examples on how to use selective unit test filtering,
>   see [Running selective unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests).

Comment: Using the command --filter seems to work but when I try a command that worked in VSTest (filter=Unit), it doesn't find my unit tests :-\  any idea why that would be?  Should the command that follows --filter be different than "=Unit"?  I also tried "=IsUnit" but no joy.

Comment: @RobMcCabe Well, they have different syntax, please see [Filter option details](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tools/dotnet-test.md#filter-option-details) for dotnet test. And here is an example to use the `--filter` in dotnet test for your reference: [DotNet Test With NUnit](https://coderscoffeehouse.com/tech/2017/12/01/dotnet-test-with-nunit.html)

Comment: For anyone else wanting to filter on Category name in Xunit, this was the argument that worked for me:   --filter "Category=Unit"

Comment: This worked for me to filter on one [TestMethod]. Just use the class name like so: `dotnet test --filter "CanPost_Add_New_Card_Date"`

Comment: The "DotNet Test With NUnit" link now seems to be dead. Any alternative recommendations?